# Document' object is not subscriptable in Python or Selenuim

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Still learning the ropes but having issues with my Document allegedly? I ran the first portion of the code fine but when I added the second portion to filter retail and marking roles. I am getting a Doucmnet object error? I have looked at the file locations and they are correct, the for loops as well. Also tried changing them from if to elif to see if it was not checking one instance or another but nope still getting the error. Anyone know why this is?

```
import docx
for jobs in job_details:
    finance_cl_template = docx.Document('D:\\Desktop\\cl automator\\finance cl template.docx')
    if "(Banking & Financial Services)" in jobs['category']:
        finance_cl_template.paragraphs[2].text = finance_cl_template.paragraphs[2].text.replace('OFD', jobs['title'])
        finance_cl_template.paragraphs[3].text = finance_cl_template.paragraphs[3].text.replace('PGA', jobs['title']).replace('ACC', jobs['recruiter'])
        finance_cl_template.paragraphs[12].text = finance_cl_template.paragraphs[12].text.replace('ACC', jobs['recruiter'])
        finance_cl_template.save(f'D:\\Desktop\\cl automator\\{jobs["title"]} Cover Letter.docx')
    if "(Retail & Consumer Products)" in jobs['category'] or "(Marketing & Communications)" in jobs['category']:
        retail_and_marketing_cl_template = docx.Document('D:\\Desktop\\cl automator\\retail and marketing cl template.docx')
        retail_and_marketing_cl_template[2].text = retail_and_marketing_cl_template.paragraphs[2].text.replace('ZFG', jobs['title'])
        retail_and_marketing_cl_template[5].text = retail_and_marketing_cl_template.paragraphs[5].text.replace('XYZ', jobs['title'])
        retail_and_marketing_cl_template[12].text = retail_and_marketing_cl_template.paragraphs[12].text.replace('ABC', jobs['recruiter'])
        retail_and_marketing_cl_template.save(f'D:\\Desktop\\cl automator\\{jobs["title"]} Cover Letter.docx')
```

Full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Desktop/Python/AI seek cover letter scraper word part3.py", line 130, in <module>
    retail_and_marketing_cl_template[2].text = retail_and_marketing_cl_template.paragraphs[2].text.replace('Spark Pukekohe', jobs['title'])
TypeError: 'Document' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Post full error

Comment: Added full error

Comment: `retail_and_marketing_cl_template` has no `[2]`

Answer (score 0):

Was missing the ".paragraphs" in the first line of:

```
retail_and_marketing_cl_template[2].text = retail_and_marketing_cl_template.paragraphs[2].text.replace('ZFG', jobs['title']).
```

Should of been:

```
retail_and_marketing_cl_template.paragraphs[2].text = retail_and_marketing_cl_template.paragraphs[2].text.replace('Spark Pukekohe', jobs['title'])
```